# Attempting to print object key pair in nodejs javascript array

Tags: node.js

I am looking to iterate and print to the console the text from the text key.
For example, if this matches a string "foo bar" I am looking to print "foo bar" to the console.

```
var stringSearcher = require('string-search');

stringSearcher.find('This is the string to search text in', 'string'  .then(function(resultArr) {
//resultArr => [ {line: 1, text: 'This is the string to search text in'} ]
  });
```

`

Comment: What is your question?  The string-search module returns the entire line that a match was found in.  That's what it does.

Comment: The output is below.  Just trying to get the text line.  


{ line: 132,
  text: '        "19:56:26;TSA-TS-DWD-TDM-DEV UP", ',
  term: /UP|DOWN/ }

{ line: 133,
  text: '        "19:56:26;ICQ-CP-DWD-TDM-DEV UP", ',
  term: /UP|DOWN/ }

{ line: 134,
  text: '        "19:56:26;TSA-MRS-DWD-TDM-DEV UP"',
  term: /UP|DOWN/ }

Comment: @jfriend00 I am just trying to get the text: XXXXXXXXXXXX portion

Comment: That would just be `resultArr[0].text`.  If that's all your question is, then please EDIT your question to just say that.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through and don't understand the .then portion of this.  I'm putting a for each loop, and it is not catching the other lines as their are multiple lines with this type of text.

Answer (score 0):

In plain nodejs I would do something like this:

```
var source = "Hello world";
var target = "Hello";
source_arr = source.split(" ");
source_arr.forEach(function(word){
  if(word.trim() === target){
    console.log("target");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to get to is the `text` property of the `resultArr` you show, then you would do this:

```
console.log(resultArr[0].text)
```

And, in real code, you probably want to verify that the array has a `.length > 0` and if there is more than one result, you might want to show all the matching results.

---

To iterate through all matching results:

```
const stringSearcher = require('string-search');

stringSearcher.find('This is the string to search text in', 'string'.then(function(resultArr) {
  for (let obj of resultArr) {
     console.log(obj.text);
  }
});
```

To explain.  `resultArr` is an array of objects.  So, when you iterate the array, you get an object at each point in the array.  Then, to get the `text` property from each object, you use `obj.text`.

Comment: I'm having trouble iterating through.

Comment: How would I get it to iterate through, but only show the text?
The below lets me go through all the array values, but i'm getting extra output I dont want.
      resultArr.forEach(function(value){
        console.log(value);
      });

Comment: @SwimJim - I added how to iterate through multiple results to my answer.  It appears you would benefit from some basic Javascript training.  There are lots of online courses and some very good books.